# What happens with reputation earned on a closed question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, closed-questions

If a question gets closed, does any reputation earned on that question go away when the question goes away?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, you still earn reputation from closed questions.

However, if the question is then *deleted*, then the reputation will be lost, with some amendments provided in the answer to another question: [Clarifying the criteria for when rep from deleted posts is maintained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/clarifying-the-criteria-for-when-rep-from-deleted-posts-is-maintained)

Comment: Do closed questions get deleted?

Comment: @Lirik They mostly do get deleted, but a few linger on and some get reopened. Note that deletion, like closing, is not a one-way process, but instead can be undone.