# Lost reputation points, when user asking the question no longer exists

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarifying the criteria for when rep from deleted posts is maintained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/clarifying-the-criteria-for-when-rep-from-deleted-posts-is-maintained)

There is a weird scenario I came across, I that know if you earn reputation and the user deletes the question the reputation remains.

However on 22<sup>nd</sup> of June, I answered a question and it was accepted. Today I found out that the question was deleted along with the user (couldn't find the user or any of his questions) and the reputation I earned is also gone.

I know this is not the expected behavior, but can I get the my reputation points back?

[image: Meaningful description goes here next time!]

Comment: You should upload the link of your accepted answer

Comment: how ?? i could not find it today.. i guess since the question is deleted, the answer is also deleted,,

Comment: opps, i forgot that part, you might want to put screenshot, i am sure it is available to you by ticking "show removed posts"

Comment: @Lucifer : updated the question with screen shot..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134103/print-invalid-syntax-error?

Comment: @jmort253 : as per the criteria, if i have more than 3 votes i should keep the reputation points... as per my screenshot the points i had earned on the question is `65` meaning i have a valid case of points being retained in my account

Comment: @avasal +3 is not the only criterion, your post must have survived for at least 2 months as well, to retain the reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On March 5th, 2012, StackExchange implemented a new plan for how reputation is handled in response to deleted posts. See the blog article titled [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/). This decision was based on community input as a result of posts that were removed that the team/community felt no longer represented the site topic.

Here is a brief summary of the rules as it applies to your situation:

> First, if you’ve contributed something worthwhile to the site, you should keep the reputation for that even if it eventually gets deleted. “Worthwhile” here is defined as,
>
> - A score of 3 or greater
> - Visible on the site for at least 60 days

In your situation, the answer was posted on June 22 and was removed the same day. Although your score was high enough to preserve the reputation, the post hadn't been on the site long enough for the reputation to be kept.

While it is somewhat depressing to lose rep in these situations, one thing we gain is the ability to recognize when a question isn't a good fit for the site and know that if we answer it, we risk that material being removed. Instead, flag those questions for closure and help keep the site clean.

Answer (score 3):

1. The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471440/sunden) who asked the question was not deleted. The question itself was deleted by a moderator after being closed as *too localized*, which I completely agree with. The answer was a simple "you missed a character" answer which is *not* helpful to future visitors.
2. No, you can't get the reputation back. You only get to keep reputation on deleted posts if it was visible on the site for at least 60 days and had a score of at least three. You only met one of those criteria.

To address your comment:

> as per my screenshot the points i had earned on the question is `65` meaning i have a valid case of points being retained in my account

You *did* lose 65 reputation for that post. Look at your screenshot again. Down below the graphs, you see *that post* with a `-65` next to it. The graph above shows `-55` because you had already gained 10 back that day.

Comment: i understand the question & answer was to simple, and it was deleted by moderator, can you pls explain what is the 10 points i gained back and why...

Comment: You deleted three of your own posts which gave you [+2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9358898), [+4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109401), and [+4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8309614) (as noted below your other post). That adds up to +10.

Comment: ohh... thanks got it.. +1 for clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

The user is alive and well, his profile [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1471440/sunden).

[His question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134103/print-invalid-syntax-error) however didn't fare as well, it got deleted by a moderator with the "Closed as too localized" reason.  It was asked on June 21st so wasn't around long enough for you to keep the rep you got from the 5 other SO users that thought your answer was helpful.

The apparent message is that helping a newbie programmer that struggles with the programming language syntax isn't appreciated and quite possibly a waste of your time.  I can only encourage you to treat this as poor judgment call from the moderator and continue contributing to SO as you have in the past.  Users like you is what keep SO humming.  You can possibly avoid these kind of deletions by quoting relevant parts from the language specification and avoiding being responsive to tag-on questions from the OP.  That will make your answer look more like a reference answer that can be useful to more than one user that might have similar problems and less like a one-on-one help session.

Comment: +1 I was just going to point that out that the user was never deleted, and the user wasn't the one who deleted the question. You beat me to it.