# How does the "not losing rep for old posts" work?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarifying the criteria for when rep from deleted posts is maintained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/clarifying-the-criteria-for-when-rep-from-deleted-posts-is-maintained)

Not that I'm complaining for the specific case I'm about to mention, but [this post was (rightfully) deleted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/11916/14) from Gaming and I lost the 20 reputation points I had gained with all my hard work.

The post was made on Dec 1 '10 at 13:24, shouldn't I have kept the reputation? (I thought that older posts retained the rep even if deleted)

Again, I'm just curious as to how this works, that's all :)

Comment: You need a score of at least 3 to keep the rep. [Details](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reported in [Reputation and Historical Archives](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/): If the post has a score of at least 3, and it has been visible in the site for at least 60 days, you keep the reputation.
If you are talking of an answer, its score was too few; if you lost 20 points in a question, its score was 4, and you should have kept your reputation.