# What happens to badges and reputation earned for a question once it is deleted?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, deleted-questions, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

I have a question of mine, which I also answered.

I got the `Self-Learner` badge and a score of +4 on the **answer** (while the **question** got a -3).

I want to delete the question (since it is unfit for SO), will I lose the badge and reputation earned?

Answer (score 1):

Badges are forever, but the points are removed again.

Comment: both the -3 and the +4?

Comment: Scores are another story. They will be gone if the post is gone.

Comment: @OfirFarchy: You are confusing vote counts with reputation. If a question is deleted, the vote counts are just as invisible as the question.

Comment: You are right, I am asking about reputation not vote-score, also edited the question.

Comment: Not fully correct. If a question has net score of 3 or more and it existed for at least 60 days before being deleted, the reputation is preserved. I am a [good test case](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/106/shadow-wizard?tab=summary) myself, as you see there are "extra" 60 points from votes on a now deleted question of mine.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Golly, that's news to me. Where is that documented? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) certainly doesn't mention that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124799/clarifying-the-criteria-for-when-rep-from-deleted-posts-is-maintained

Comment: @Mat: Ah, I missed that part of the blog post completely. The faq should be updated (I'll probably do that myself).