# Why was my historic 'great question' closed and what happens next?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions, historical-lock

I'm the author of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/what-is-the-best-css-framework-and-are-they-worth-the-effort), I'd like to understand why it has been closed (after being open for 3 1/2 years!) and what is going to happen to it next?

The suggestion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53397/what-happens-with-reputation-earned-on-a-closed-question) is that its now a candidate for deletion.

I obviously have a vested interest in the question since I asked it! But as a user, it doesn't really fill me with joy to see what has been considered a 'Great Question' (100 votes or more by peers) to be closed and now a candidate for deletion.

I have two motions I'd like to be considered:

1. Re-open the question.
2. Close, but lock the question since its been around for 3 1/2 years.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question cannot be reopened by today's standards as it's essentially a polling/shopping question, and we try not to keep those open anymore.

Most questions do get deleted after they're closed and have not been salvaged in any way. However, in light of [recent concerns for the preservation of historic 'great questions'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124439/community-led-deletionism-a-protocol-for-sanity), some of said questions may receive a historical lock if they have lasting value to the community and the Internet.

To that end, we'll consider locking your question as historically significant, to freeze the question and its answers and prevent them from being deleted. The question and its answers are great (though I should say one of them doesn't really need to be kept around since the link is dead), so it would be a shame to delete the entire thing.

<del>So chances are we'll go with #2.</del> **EDIT:** OK, I've locked it. It's yours to keep forever, and nobody can pry it even from your cold, dead hands. Not even yourself.

Comment: *Psst!* You have a diamond. You should probably go ahead and initiate that "historically significant" process before all of the Meta deletionists jump on this one. I concur that this looks like a good candidate; at least some of the answers are quite useful and informative.