# Reputation on closed questions?

Tags: support, reputation, closed-questions

I though that once a question or answer was deleted or closed, the points awarded/decucted by up/down votes were nullified.  I just had a closed question get down voted and it deducted my rep.  Why is dv even allowed on a closed question, and was I wrong about closure/deletion nullifying the rep from votes?

Comment: Only deletion reverses reputation. Closure does not.

Comment: @animuson for the sake of precision, reputation is sometimes preserved even if post is deleted, see [Deleted posts should not influence reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124754/165773): _"you should keep the reputation for... * A score of 3 or greater * Visible on the site for at least 60 days"_

Answer (score 2):

When a question is deleted, the upvotes/downvotes are removed.  When a question is closed, they remain.  You can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53397/what-happens-with-reputation-earned-on-a-closed-question) what happens to your rep when a question is closed.